# Query not being executed with async await in Node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, async-await

I am trying to make a GET request in my node js application, but for some reason its not working with async await. It works when i use the callback chain but when i try to execute the same query with async await its giving me an error:

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
>       at JSON.stringify ()

my code:

```
router.get("/getuser", async(req,res)=>{
const emailexists= 'select * from users'
try{
    const results=await connection.query(emailexists)
    res.send(results)
}catch(err){
    console.log(err)
}
})
```

I am using mysql as database. Can anyone please help?

Comment: What is connection.query? Does it really return a promise?

Comment: Are you using the promise version of mysql?

Comment: @jfriend00 i used an insert query with async await in another route and it worked just fine.

Comment: @Quentin connection.query basically executes my query

Comment: @FaheelSattar — What **precisely** is it? Show us the library. Don't just give a vague description of what it does. We can tell that from the name! **Does it really return a promise**?

Comment: yes it does return a promise @Quentin. I already speicifed in my question that the query is perfectly being executed with the callback that means it is returning a promise. Its not working with async await.

Comment: "the query is perfectly being executed with the callback" — It really doesn't. Functions that take callbacks generally do so instead of returning promises.

Comment: @Quentin can you help finding a way to execute this query with async await

Comment: @Quentin I am using async await in order to get myself away from the callback hell problem. If some query is executed with callback it should be executed with async await because promises are handled in three ways 1) Callbacks 2) Promise chain 3) Async await. Simply what i want to achieve is excecuting my query with async await and send my result to the front end

Comment: And you **still** haven't told us what library your connection object is coming from.

Comment: mysql library @Quentin

Comment: This one? https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql ? Version 2.17.1 of it?

Comment: yes @Quentin thats exaclty what the library and the version is

Comment: The documentation doesn't mention promises. The documentation gives no example where `.then()` is used. `connection.query` **doesn't return a promise**.

Comment: have a look at this https://codeburst.io/node-js-mysql-and-async-await-6fb25b01b628 @Quentin

Comment: @FaheelSattar — That article says that you have to wrap connection.query in a promise manually because the module doesn't have promise support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysql library you are using does not support promises.  So, `connection.query(emailexists)` does not return a promise and thus using `await` with it does not do anything useful and does not wait for the result.

You can either manually promisify the specific functions you want to use, use a [third party promise wrapper for mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql) or you can use the newer [`mysql2/promise` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper) which has built-in promise support.  See that link for programming examples.